# Test coverage for ERB templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, testing, code-coverage, erb

Is there any chance to check if template line was executed.

Ideally, something like simplecov for .rb code. [Simplecov can't](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/38)

Answer (score 0):

I think Codecov might work for you. It's based on Simplecov but has some expanded functionality on top of it which is pretty nice.